# Modulus of exponential function with real and complex arguments

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function, absolute-value

Can anyone please explain why 
$$|e^{\frac12 \sin(2x) }|\le e^{1/2}$$
for all real $x$, 
 while $$|e^{-i\sin(x)^{2}}|=1$$ 
for all real $x$?

Comment: $|e^{ix}|=1$ for all real $x$

Comment: Without quantifying over $x$, it's not possible to answer this question.

Comment: what do you mean please?

Comment: @user120768 Is $x$ supposed to be real? If so, the first equality is wrong, in general. If $x$ can be complex, then both are wrong, in general.

Comment: @user120768 What egreg said, plus do you want to attach $\forall x$ or $\exists x$ to the equalities?

Comment: you are right,the first equality is actually supposed to be an inequality (<=) and x is real. sorry about the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \in \mathbb R$, then $-1 \le \sin 2x \le 1$.  Since exponentiation by a real number is a monotonically increasing function, $$|e^{(\sin 2x)/2}|$$ attains its maximum when $\sin 2x$ is maximized; i.e., when $\sin 2x = 1$.  (The absolute value is irrelevant because $e^x > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.  It follows that $$e^{(\sin 2x)/2} \le e^{1/2}.$$

For the second identity, we note that $$|e^{i\theta}| = |\cos \theta + i \sin \theta| = \sqrt{\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta} = 1$$ for any $\theta \in \mathbb R$.  Therefore $$|e^{-i\sin x^2}| = 1$$ since $-\sin x^2$ or $-\sin^2 x$ (whichever you prefer) is a real number.